# Redirect all pages except 1 to a single Temporary Unavailable Page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

We have a fully functional website but the backend is going down for maintenance, so we want to redirect all our customers to www.example.com/unavailable. Except for 1 page www.example.com/admin since this is the admin page where we put the unavailable page on and off.

**So my question:** 
Is it possible to turn routes on and off like this:

**Example code for routes.rb:**

```
  if Settings.unavailable
    get "*", to: "/unavailable", except: "/admin"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from the post from Michal, I've adapted his answer to the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_maintenance

  def check_maintenance
    if Settings.first.maintenance && request.fullpath.split("?")[0].gsub("/","") != 'unavailable' && (request.fullpath.split("?")[0].exclude? "admin") # or other conditions
      redirect_to '/unavailable'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put conditions in your routes.rb but you won't be able to detect what is the current url. You should put this logic in before_filter in ApplicationController (or other top level controller):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_maintenance

  def check_maintenance
    if Settings.unavailable && action_name != 'unavailable' # or other conditions
      redirect_to '/unavailable'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Like you say I need more conditions because now I'm going into an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help, please notice my answer.